# Save changes from dataGridView to SQL Server DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, datagridview

I have a form with dataGridView to display content of table Attendance

```
    TagID      SessionID       ScanningTime
    ---------------------------------------
    4820427      Test1       14/08/2013 18:12
```

I would like to add a record manually to the table to look like this....

```
    TagID      SessionID       ScanningTime
    ---------------------------------------
    4820000      Test1       14/08/2013 18:12
    0000001      Test2       15/08/2012 17:00
```

...and save changes to SQL Server database after button has been clicked.

I have tried creating UPDATE query:

```
command.Text = "UPDATE Attendance
SET TagID= @tagNo, SessionID= @sessionNo, ScanningTime= @scantime";
```

But I'm not sure how to assign values from DGV to parameters.

What is the correct way to save changes from dataGridView to SQL Server database?

Please note that I do not use DataSet or TableAdapter when working with DGV.

Comment: The correct way is open ended question but to answer your question the correct way would be to start writing some code and testing out if what you have written yields the expected results.. show some `initiative / effort`

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to consume the `RowsAdded` method of the `DataGridView` and cache the necessary information to `INSERT` the data:

```
// new form field for caching
private List<DataGridViewRow> _addedRowsCache = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender,
    DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = e.RowIndex; i < e.RowIndex + e.RowCount; i++)
    {
        _addedRowsCache.Add(dataGridView.Rows[i]);
    }
}
```

and then when you're ready to submit the data to the database:

```
// new class field to store the INSERT sql
private string _insertSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl (field1, field2) VALUES (@field1, @field2)";

// this block goes inside the click event
if (_addedRowsCache.Count > 0)
{
    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        c.Open();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in _addedRowsCache)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c))
            {
                // add any parameter values, I don't know where `val(n)`
                // comes from here. Maybe from the `DataBoundItem`
                // off the `DataGridViewRow`, or maybe from a `Cell`
                // out of the `Cells` collection of the `DataGridViewRow`
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", val1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", val2);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful thanks. I'm looking for a way to update the table if ANY changes been made (not only adding a row, but also modifying existing records)

Comment: @jaspernorth, a couple things. First, if you find `RowsAdded` doesn't work for the caching, you can also try `UserAddedRow`. Second, as far as updates, cache the `DataGridViewRow` using the `CellBeginEdit` event. The event args will let you get back to the row. However, cache those rows in a different list so you know the difference.